# Rendering React (with html props) in legacy web app

Tags: php, reactjs, vite

Assuming I have a legacy PHP+JS website, and I managed to use Vite to render components inside the legacy HTML this way:

```
<div id="last-activities"></div>
<?php
   echo vite('src/components/HomeWidgets/Activity.tsx');
?>
```

While in my React:

```
const elementID = "last-activities";
try {
  const element = document.getElementById(elementID);
  const root = createRoot(element);
  const props = element.dataset;
  root.render(
    <ProviderWrapper>
      <Activity {...props} />
    </ProviderWrapper>
  );
} catch (e) {
  console.warn("Cant find id #" + elementID, document);
}
```

and it actually works, but what if:

- How should I pass HTML content to the component? e.g card component that accepts children?
- For regular props, I used data-* attributes and converted them to props (and it works)